# Getting error while using -c option in mailx command

Tags: mailx

I'm running a script to send a mail with few lines. Requirement is I need to add few people  in cc.

So I have created below scripts. For people who needs to be in TO and CC , I have created 2 separate files as you can see below :

---

echo Reminder mail sending `date`!!!

CC_LIST=`cat cc_list.maillist`

TO_LIST=`cat to_list.maillist`

echo "$CC_LIST"

echo "$TO_LIST"

cat test_mail.txt |  mailx -r abc@xyz.com -s "subject" "$TO_LIST" -c "$CC_LIST"

So without -c "$CC_LIST", my script running fine but while using -c option it gives error as below :

-c... User unknown

As it seems considering -c as another mailed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The `mailx` utility assumes that the operands at the end of the command line are all addresses to send the email to.

Just make sure that all options are specified before any of the recipients' addresses. In other words, swap `-c "$CC_LIST"` with `"$TO_LIST"`.

Comment: I have checked several options like just passing mail ids without list or placing cc before to....every time the error is same as it didn't recognize command -c....treating it as new mail id -c !!!